# Multi lines in a table cell starting from left

Tags: tables

I am trying to make a table in latex have same outline as this table below.
[image]

After some attempts, this is what I get at the moment.
[image]

I really want the two dot points to align with each other, starting from the left hand side.
Below is how I attempt it,
package I used

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx} %% tables
\usepackage{ltablex} 
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~} %%% bullet in table
```

Table code

```
 \begin{center}
 \begin{table}[H]

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}
{\begin{tabular}{|c |c |c |c |}  \hline
\textit{\textbf{Governing Equations}} & \textit{\textbf{Basic Assumptions}} & \textit{\textbf{Advantages}} & \textit{\textbf{Disadvantages }}\\ 
 \hline
 \textbf{Navier-Stokes} &  \makecell{ \tabitem Incompressible Newtonian fluid \\ \tabitem  Only gravity is considered as body force } &  \tabitem Comprehensive &  \tabitem Computationally expensive \\
 \hline
& & & \\
 \hline

\end{tabular}}
 \caption[Simulation Costs]{Simulation costs based on actual walltime per simulation time per CPU and per control volume (CV). Approximates were applied, due to some inevitable factors, such as queueing time on Tinaroo.}
\label{tab:SimulationCosts}

   \end{table}
\end{center}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of approximately emulating an itemize environment, I prefer to use one, with the facilities of `enumitem`. I added some padding with the `\setcellgapes`command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{ltablex,booktabs,ragged2e, enumitem, makecell, float, textcomp}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~} %%% bullet in table

\begin{document}

 \begin{table}[H]
 \footnotesize\keepXColumns
 \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\itshape}
 \setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells
 \setlist[itemize]{wide =0pt, leftmargin=*, nosep, before=\vspace{-\baselineskip}, after = \vspace{-\baselineskip}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c |X |c |c |} \hline
\thead{Governing Equations} & \thead{Basic Assumptions} & \thead{Advantages} & \thead{Disadvantages}\\
 \hline
 \textbf{Navier-Stokes} & \mbox{}\begin{itemize} \item Incompressible Newtonian fluid
 \item Only gravity is considered as body force\end{itemize} & \tabitem Comprehensive & \tabitem Computationally expensive \\
 \hline
& & & \\
 \hline
\end{tabularx}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Bernard Thanks for answering, but when I combined this table, there are some funny lines all around the place, not sure why. BTW, how to insert images in the comment, I tired ctrl+G, no working

Comment: It's only the `showframe`  option of geometry, to check nothing overflows. Simply  remove the option.

Comment: @ZhifangHu You can't insert images in comments, but you can upload them to e.g. Imgur and post a link.

Comment: @Bernard Hi Bernard, I know this question has been here for a while, but  after I used tabularx, i find my table numbering is not right, whenever i use this tabularx, the table name will be a even number, say for example, i have 2 tables should be named table 1, 2 respectively, but it turned out to be table 2 and 4, any suggestions how to fix it? thanks in advance.

Comment: @ZhifangHu: This is due to loading `ltablex`, which is done to  break `tabularx`  tables across pages: the syntax has to be the same as for `long table`, which is not a float. You have to put the caption inside the `firsthead`  section of the table, and remove the `table` environment, since the tabularx will not float. Alternatively, if you don't have long tabularx which you want to break across pages, don't load `ltablex` and use the standard way to code the caption.